# Sci-fi book about humans living on another planet and reflecting on Earth origins

Tags: story-identification, books, space-colonization

I came across a book recommendation that really piqued my interest, and am having trouble remembering the details to sufficiently find it via search engines.

Here is what I can remember:

- I remember that the book is about humans living on another planet and reflecting on life on Earth.
- I don't think that the book had very much to do with aliens, but more about colonization of another nearby planet.
- I remember coming across this via an Elon Musk tweet about SpaceX's Starship, so I believe it would be something similar to what is trying to be done there.

What I am really interested in is a somewhat realistic book where a story is told about humans colonizing another planet and discovering what it's like to become a multi-planetary species, and the lessons learned from Earth and sustained contact with Earth.

Comment: When did you hear about this book, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you remember any details about what the cover looked like?

Comment: More information would be very helpful here -- this is very little to go on.  Plot snippets, character information, recollection of the cover art?  Your description could fit Bradbury's *The Martian Chronicles* but it could also fit a number of other thoughtful pieces aimed more at good writing than action-adventure.

Comment: Musk has tweeted about a number of SF novels, but none that seem similar to your description. Asimov's Foundation series seem to be his favourite but Earth is not mentioned in that (until the retcon in the final books where we find Earth is radioactive).

Comment: @ZeissIkon _Martian Chronicles_ was my exact thought upon reading this Q.

Comment: Once he tweeted “Foundation Series & Zeroth Law are fundamental to creation of SpaceX”. Maybe that points to "Robots and Empire" where the zeroth law was introduced.